# Add an Array to numpy sub array

Tags: python, numpy

i have an array `[[[1],[2]]]` and i want to add `[3]` to get `[[[1],[2],[3]]]`

what i've tried so far

```
my_array = numpy.array([[[1],[2]]])
print(my_array.shape, my_array)

to_append = numpy.array([3])
print(to_append.shape, to_append)

# i want [[[1],[2],[3]]]
my_array[0] = numpy.append(my_array[0], to_append)
```

but i get

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (3) into shape (2,1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [`numpy.concatenate`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html):

```
>>> np.concatenate([my_array, [[[3]]]], 1)
array([[[1],
        [2],
        [3]]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [numpy.concatenate](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) could work here but you have to make sure the arrays are the same in one dimension

Answer (score 1):

```
numpy.append(my_array, to_append[None,:,None], 1)
```

Result

```
array([[[1],
        [2],
        [3]]])
```